# Starting nginx with systemctl fails, but running the command manually doesn't

Tags: linux, nginx, systemd, systemctl

On Arch Linux, for some reason, when I try to start nginx with the command "systemctl start nginx", it fails, with this being the output of "systemctl status nginx":

```
Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled)
Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2013-10-30 16:22:17 EDT; 5s ago
Process: 9835 ExecStop=/usr/bin/chroot --userspec=http:http /home/nginx /usr/bin/nginx -g pid /run/nginx.pid; -s quit (code=exited, status=126)
Process: 3982 ExecStart=/usr/bin/chroot --userspec=http:http /home/nginx /usr/bin/nginx -g pid /run/nginx.pid; daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Process: 10967 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/chroot --userspec=http:http /home/nginx /usr/bin/nginx -t -q -g pid /run/nginx.pid; daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=126)
Main PID: 3984 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
CGroup: /system.slice/nginx.service
```

...but when I run

```
/usr/bin/chroot --userspec=http:http /home/nginx /usr/bin/nginx -t -q -g "pid /run/nginx.pid; daemon on; master_process on;"
```

and then

```
/usr/bin/chroot --userspec=http:http /home/nginx /usr/bin/nginx -g "pid /run/nginx.pid; daemon on; master_process on;"
```

as root, all it does is return a warning, but works just fine:

```
nginx: [warn] the "user" directive makes sense only if the master process runs with super-user privileges, ignored in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:1
```

Why is it doing that?

edit:
After looking in /var/log/messages.log, I found this:

```
/usr/bin/chroot: failed to run command ‘/usr/bin/nginx’: Permission denied
```

but ls -l /home/nginx/usr/bin/nginx returns this:

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 797040 Oct 25 18:24 nginx
```

..and every directory leading up to /home/nginx/usr/bin/ is chmodded a+x

Comment: Didn't `systemctl status` show you any log entries? Check all the relevant logs.

Comment: Sometimes a service will generate logs that do not show when you run `systemctl status`, especially if they die very early in startup. Look at `/var/log/messages` for hints in these cases.

Comment: @MichaelHampton @joemiller I didn't find anything in systemctl status, but I did find this in /var/log/messages: `/usr/bin/chroot: failed to run command ‘/usr/bin/nginx’: Permission denied`

Comment: Why using /usr/bin/chroot? You can do similar stuff (user, rootdirectory, workingdirectory) directly with the systemd unit file

Comment: @Kdecherf nginx is running in a chroot jail. All I did was follow [Arch Linux's Nginx](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/nginx) page's instructions.

Answer (score 3):

I experienced the same problem and it was due to **SELinux**.

To check if SELinux is running:

```
# getenforce
```

To disable SELinux until next reboot:

```
# setenforce Permissive
```

Restart Nginx and see if the problem persists. If you would like to permanently alter the settings you can edit `/etc/sysconfig/selinux`

If SELinux is your problem you can run the following to allow nginx to serve your www directory (make sure you turn SELinux back on before testing this. i.e, `setenforce Enforcing`)

```
# chcon -Rt httpd_sys_content_t /path/to/www
```

If you're still having issues take a look at the boolean flags in `getsebool -a`, in particular you may need to turn on `httpd_can_network_connect` for network access

```
# setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect on
```

For me it was enough to allow http to serve my www directory.

Comment: This answer is a little bit late, and my nginx setup runs fine today (server reinstallations, etc), but it doesn't seem that Arch Linux has SELinux. `getenforce`/`setenforce` are unknown commands, and `/etc/sysconfig` isn't an existing directory, but I appreciate you trying to answer it. :)